# ajax jquery facebook open graph tags not used

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

i get my pagedata from an xml and i want this data to be shown when shared, below is my code:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "data/artikels.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml){
                oArticle = $(xml).find('article:eq('+id+')');
                var regExp = /.*(?:youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;
                var match = oArticle.find('youtube').text().match(regExp);  
                $('head').append('<meta property="og:title" content="'+oArticle.find('title').text()+'" />'
                    +'<meta property="og:description" content="'+oArticle.find('shortcontent').text().replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;')+'" />'
                    +'<meta property="og:image" content="'+oArticle.find('image').text()+'" />').trigger('create');  
                $('#container').append('<div id="title_article">'+oArticle.find('title').text()+'</div>'
                    +'<div id="date_article">'+oArticle.find('date').text()+'</div>'
                    +'<iframe width="600" height="315" src='+'"'+'http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+match[1]
                    +'<div id="content_article">'+oArticle.find('fullcontent').text()+'</div>').trigger('create');

            }
        })
```

When i enter my url in facebook debugger other images/titles/descriptions are taken, the same happens when i just share. Is there any way to solve this?

Kind regards

Toon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook generates the meta content of the link by fetching your plain HTML page. It won't run your JavaScript code.

You are better off handling this in your back-end script and serving the meta tags when the page loads instead of loading it with AJAX. In general, if you have an AJAX request in your site that takes no input from the user, you are doing something wrong, as this could have been generated by the server before serving the HTML to the user. (thus reducing the amount of requests the user's browser has to make)

Comment: this is the regular way to parse an xml with jquery tough :( i dont use any serverside code atm so gonna be hard

Comment: You can parse XML with any server-side language, and that is the only way to achieve what you need with it.

Comment: guess i will need to think about it yes... i did it client side because i needed to be able to store my app in html 5 localstorage

Comment: You can fetch the data at server-side and just pass it inside an element, then just fetch and save it at the client side, without the AJAX.

Comment: how would i pass it inside an element then? o.O

Comment: Output it into a JavaScript object and then manipulate it on the client side. The actual implementation depends on your needs; but either ways, in order for Facebook to see the meta tags, you need to output that tags on server side.
If you choose to still pull content through AJAX for your HTML5 storage, do that, but leave the meta tags server-side.